# Trying to animate an m x n matrix one row at a time

Tags: matrix, animation

I would like to use ArrayPlot[list, Mesh->True] if possible and I essentially want it to show 1 row at a time and animate the changes it goes through.

[image: context]

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure if this is what you want. But you gave no example.

```
mat = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10, 10}];
Manipulate[ArrayPlot[mat[[1 ;; n, All]], Mesh -> True],
 {{n, 2, "row"}, 2, Length@mat, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]